# why my app doesn't look like same in different devices although I used dp. Isn't dp should be shown same in different size devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, pixel, dpi

I just finished my first app and tried to test it in different devices.
but i found that the layout doesn't look like as I expected.so i looked up android developer pages and learned what is dp. In android developer doc, they say i shouldn't do hard code in xml file, but i don't understand why. because dp literally means Density-independent Pixel which should be shown differently depend on density(mdpi,hdpi,...) of device. for example

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />
```

this button should be shown as in 100px(mdpi), 150px(hdpi), 200px(xhdpi), 300px(xxhdpi), 400px(xxxhdpi) right? so then if i do hard code like above, the button should be shown as same size(to user) so why i should not do hard code? and why my app is not same as i see in different devices? I will be really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you exactly mean. But since this is your first App you should not worry much. As you practice more and more you will come across various ways to make your objects responsive to different screen sizes. For starters, you can look into the use of
`app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=""` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=""` or   `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""`. But the key I think is to always stick to constraint layout, if you want a responsive screen.
Thank you!

Comment: happy to help! :)